# Como desenvolver carregamento de videos relacionados

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quero criar um Script que funcione como em sites do gênero: [dailymotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/br), [metacafe](http://www.metacafe.com) e outros tantos repositórios de vídeos que fazem isso. Quando o usuário abre um vídeo ele bota o vídeo pra rodar dentro duma `div` cujo `id` será definido para isso, em outro elemento `HTML` também com `id` traz o carregamento dos demais videos relacionados ao qual selecionei, ou seja, vídeos similares, recomendados, etc.

A intenção aqui é saber como funciona essa modelagem de programação, algumas idéias serão bem recebidas e melhor se houver um exemplo prático/didático.

## Exemplo

```
var soma = 0
while (soma < 1000){
    soma += parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
    document.write (soma + "<br>")
}
```

Neste exemplo declaro uma variável e a inicio com 0 e com um laço `for` somo um número aleatório do 1 ao 100 até chegar a 1.000, imprimindo o valor da variável soma depois de cada operação.

Desejo criar algo `client-side` e não `server-side` trabalho minhas idéias com este combo `html`, `css` e `js`. E o código ele recarrega de modo aleatório do 1 ao 100, os arquivos que tenho são nomeados por número.

```js
 // chamar função apenas 1 vez!!!
var str = window.setInterval('carregar()', 2000);

window.setInterval('window.clearInterval(str)', 3000);

var dir = 'https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails';

var ext = 'jpg';

// função responsável por desenvolver carregamento de videos relacionados
carregar = function(){

var soma = 0;

while (soma < 100){

soma += parseInt(Math.random() * 10);

document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML += "<img src='"+ dir + "/" + soma + "." + ext +"' onclick='limpar(); carregar();'><br>";

    } 

}

// limpa playlist para popular novamente com demais videos relacionados
limpar = function() {

document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML = '';

}
```

```css
#playlist {

 width:250px; 

    height:100%;

 padding:15px; 

 float: right;

border: 1px solid silver;

overflow: auto;

}

img {

padding: 10 10 10 10;

margin: 0 auto;

width: 196px; 

height: 110px;

text-align: center;

}

img:hover { 

background-color: steelblue; 

cursor: pointer; 

}
```

```html
<div id="playlist"> &nbsp; </div>
```

---

Sei que a pergunta é ampla, mas não sei nem por onde começar a desenvolver algo do tipo. Qualquer auxilio sera bem vindo.

Comment: O problema é que a pergunta é pertinente, mas existem inúmeros modos de se fazer isso, js, uma linguagem de back-end ou usando a ajuda de um banco de dados

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Até tenho uma teoria em mente, mas sempre gosto de ver outros modelos de código-fonte. Não sou tão orgulhoso que não possa aprender e nem tão leigo que não posso ensinar.

Comment: client side vai ser algo mais trabalhoso, ao meu ver, server side com os dados salvos em um banco de dados relacional, seria muito mais simples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue meu modelo:

```css
      body {
           background-color: whitesmoke;
       }

        .player a span {
            display: none;
        }

        .player a:hover span {
            background: transparent;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 100;
        }

        .player a:hover span img {
            background: blue;
        }

        .player a:hover em {
            z-index: 1;
            display: none;
        }

        .player a img {
            border: white 1px solid;
        }

        .player a:hover img {
            border: white 1px solid;
        }

        #snapshot {
            width: 480px;
            height: 320px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            background-color: white;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: 480px 320px;
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #playlist {
           padding: 25px 35px 35px 35px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100%;
            float: right;
            border: 1px solid red;
            overflow: auto;
            position: relevante;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
           background-color: white;
        }

        img {
            width: 196px;
            height: 110px;
        }

        img:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
    <h1>Vídeo Play!</h1>

    <div class="player">
        <a href="#">
<span>
<img style='background:transparent;border:0;margin:100px 0 0 145px;' src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails/run.png" height="480" width="320" />
</span>
<img id="snapshot" height="480" width="320"/>
</a>
    </div>

    <div id="playlist"> &nbsp; </div>


    <script>
        // Chamar função apenas 1 vez!!!
        var str = window.setInterval('carregar()', 1500);

        window.setInterval('window.clearInterval(str)', 3000);

        var dir = 'https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/thumbnails';

        var ext = 'jpg';

        // Função responsável por desenvolver carregamento de videos relacionados
        carregar = function() {

            var soma = 0;

            while (soma < 100) {
// Partindo de 0 - 100, carregar aleatoriamente 10 arquivos na Playlist. Sendo 1 arquivo único(sem duplicar). Assim 0..100 * 10 + 1. Veja:
                soma += parseInt((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

                document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML += "<img src='" + dir + "/" + soma + "." + ext + "' onclick='limpar(); carregar(); exibir(this.src)'><br>";

            }
        }

        // Limpa playlist para popular novamente com demais videos relacionados
        limpar = function() {
            document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML = '';
        }

        // Pega o atributo src da tag image na Playlist e insere no player/snapshot
        function exibir(fig) {
            document.getElementById("snapshot").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + fig + "')";
        }
    </script>
```

**w3schools** - [veja uma demonstração](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSMK4MEFPBY7)